# Responsive Card Layout CSS Design not Fixed

Tags: javascript, css, cardlayout

I want to make cards which are responsive but not fixed. What changes should I make to CSS so that it change change their sizes accordingly.

Here is the fiddle link for this [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hawkeye15/u1j9tpx9/2/)

The cars should change its size with resizing window however the position of the button should be at the bottom only, and in spite of content, size of all cards should be same.

**CARD.HTML**

```
           <div class = 'col-md-2'>
      <div class="mycard text-center"> 
      <div class="card-header"> 
      <p1>HEADING 1</p1> 
      </div> 
      <div class = "card-block">   
      <div id = "container"> 
      Something will be written here
      </div>  
      </div> 
      <div class = "card-name"> 
      <p2> MY NAME 1 </p2> 
      </div> 
      <div class = 'cardfooter'> 
      <div class='dropdownAD'>
      <button class='dropbtnAD' onclick="AddIt()">Add Courses</button>
      </div> 
      <div class='dropdownGR'><button class='dropbtnGR'>Remove</button>
      </div>
      </div> 
      </div> 

      <div class="mycard text-center"> 
      <div class="card-header"> 
      <p1>HEADING 2</p1> 
      </div> 
      <div class = "card-block">   
      <div id = "container"> 
      Something will be written here
      </div>  
      </div> 
      <div class = "card-name"> 
      <p2> MY NAME 2 , WHOLE PURPOSE IS TO MAKE TO NEXT LINE TO MAKE BUTTONS AT FIXED PLACE </p2> 
      </div> 
      <div class = 'cardfooter'> 
      <div class='dropdownAD'>
      <button class='dropbtnAD' onclick="AddIt()">Add Courses</button>
      </div> 
      <div class='dropdownGR'><button class='dropbtnGR'>Remove</button>
      </div>
      </div> 
      </div> 

      <div class="mycard text-center"> 
      <div class="card-header"> 
      <p1>HEADING 3</p1> 
      </div> 
      <div class = "card-block">   
      <div id = "container"> 
      Something will be written here
      </div>  
      </div> 
      <div class = "card-name"> 
      <p2> MY NAME 3</p2> 
      </div> 
      <div class = 'cardfooter'> 
      <div class='dropdownAD'>
      <button class='dropbtnAD' onclick="AddIt()">Add Courses</button>
      </div> 
      <div class='dropdownGR'><button class='dropbtnGR'>Remove</button>
      </div>
      </div> 
      </div> 

      <div class="mycard text-center"> 
      <div class="card-header"> 
      <p1>HEADING 4</p1> 
      </div> 
      <div class = "card-block">   
      <div id = "container"> 
      Something will be written here
      </div>  
      </div> 
      <div class = "card-name"> 
      <p2> MY NAME 4</p2> 
      </div> 
      <div class = 'cardfooter'> 
      <div class='dropdownAD'>
      <button class='dropbtnAD' onclick="AddIt()">Add Courses</button>
      </div> 
      <div class='dropdownGR'><button class='dropbtnGR'>Remove</button>
      </div>
      </div> 
      </div> 
      </div>
```

**CARD.CSS**

```
      .mycard {
      background-color: #FFC20A;
      color: black;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      text-align: center;
      height: 200px;
      width: 230px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      font-size: 12px;
      }


      .card-header {
      color: black;
      height:24px;
      padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;

      }

      .card-block {
      background-color: #b2b2b2;
      color: black;
      border-radius: 10px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 220px;
      }

      .card-name {
        height:35px;
      }

      .cardfooter {
      border-radius: 5px;
      width:100%;
      height: 34px;
      bottom:0;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is change the card's `width` to `min-width`. This will force the card to be `100%` width until `230px`. As you can see in my altered version of your JSFiddle.

What you should keep in mind is your card content is broken down into rows of content. Each row looks like it should be 100% width of the card, therefore you don't need to actually apply a width to the content, just provide `display: block`. This will force it to be 100% width of it's parent. With content being 100% width of it's parent it's flexibility will always be dependent on the parent. Thus you can set the parents width to 100%, 50%, 200px whatever, the content will always follow.

Let me know if you need me to clarify anything :)

```css
.mycard {
background-color: #FFC20A;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
text-align: center;
height: 200px;
min-width: 230px;
border-radius: 10px;
font-size: 12px;
}


.card-header {
color: black;
height:24px;
padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;

}

.card-block {
background-color: #b2b2b2;
color: black;
border-radius: 10px;
height: 100px;
width: 220px;
}

.card-name {
  height:35px;
}

.cardfooter {
border-radius: 5px;
width:100%;
height: 34px;
bottom:0;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'col-md-2'>
<div class="mycard text-center"> 
<div class="card-header"> 
<p1>HEADING 1</p1> 
</div> 
<div class = "card-block">   
<div id = "container"> 
Something will be written here
</div>  
</div> 
<div class = "card-name"> 
<p2> MY NAME 1 </p2> 
</div> 
<div class = 'cardfooter'> 
<div class='dropdownAD'>
<button class='dropbtnAD' onclick="AddIt()">Add Courses</button>
</div> 
<div class='dropdownGR'><button class='dropbtnGR'>Remove</button>
</div>
</div> 
</div> 

<div class="mycard text-center"> 
<div class="card-header"> 
<p1>HEADING 2</p1> 
</div> 
<div class = "card-block">   
<div id = "container"> 
Something will be written here
</div>  
</div> 
<div class = "card-name"> 
<p2> MY NAME 2 , WHOLE PURPOSE IS TO MAKE TO NEXT LINE TO MAKE BUTTONS AT FIXED PLACE </p2> 
</div> 
<div class = 'cardfooter'> 
<div class='dropdownAD'>
<button class='dropbtnAD' onclick="AddIt()">Add Courses</button>
</div> 
<div class='dropdownGR'><button class='dropbtnGR'>Remove</button>
</div>
</div> 
</div> 

<div class="mycard text-center"> 
<div class="card-header"> 
<p1>HEADING 3</p1> 
</div> 
<div class = "card-block">   
<div id = "container"> 
Something will be written here
</div>  
</div> 
<div class = "card-name"> 
<p2> MY NAME 3</p2> 
</div> 
<div class = 'cardfooter'> 
<div class='dropdownAD'>
<button class='dropbtnAD' onclick="AddIt()">Add Courses</button>
</div> 
<div class='dropdownGR'><button class='dropbtnGR'>Remove</button>
</div>
</div> 
</div> 

<div class="mycard text-center"> 
<div class="card-header"> 
<p1>HEADING 4</p1> 
</div> 
<div class = "card-block">   
<div id = "container"> 
Something will be written here
</div>  
</div> 
<div class = "card-name"> 
<p2> MY NAME 4</p2> 
</div> 
<div class = 'cardfooter'> 
<div class='dropdownAD'>
<button class='dropbtnAD' onclick="AddIt()">Add Courses</button>
</div> 
<div class='dropdownGR'><button class='dropbtnGR'>Remove</button>
</div>
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand the concept of display:block ? Its is kind of substitute for width : 100% or something else?

Comment: In a way, yes it is a substitute for width: 100%. A good description can be found [on learn layout.com](http://learnlayout.com/display.html). "A block-level element starts on a new line and stretches out to the left and right as far as it can."